# Anchor link is not diplaying in Gmail

Tags: html, cordova

When i am trying to send the link like this

```
 <a href="fswapp://">Test</a>
```

i have also tried this but the result is same.

```
 <a onClick="window.open('fswapp://','_blank')">Test</a>
```

Gmail is not displaying the link. it is necessary to send link like given in my code.

Please suggest any solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me.can u check whether you added any styles for <a>

Comment: on it's not displaying in Gmail inbox.